# Django: New Field Addition Gives Error while doing makemigration

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Post models for blog:

```
сlass Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name="blog_posts",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
........
........
```

And I want to add a Tag to the project, so I made a Tag model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name
```

I added this to the Post model:

```
tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name="blog_tag",
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But `makemigration` give to me an error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'tag' to post without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

So why i have to populate existing rows? And how i can to live the rows empty?
P.S. If i chose 1) i still have an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have data in your db and now you are adding a new column `tag` in your database table, which is also `not null`.

So django is saying that either you provide one-default data for the previously existing rows or you make this new column (`tag`) a null value (by adding `null=True` in arguments of the field) so that already existing rows will fill it with `null`.

Comment: Thanks that worked out. Now my models looks like this :

Comment: 'class Post(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name="blog_tag",
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            blank=True,
                            null=True)'